# Second order derivatives in Ito formula for Brownian motion and local martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

Itô's formula for a $\mathcal{C}^2$ function of two variables F reads:
\begin{align}
F(X_t, Y_t) &= F(X_0, Y_0) + \int_0^t \frac{\partial F}{dx}(X_s, Y_s) \,  dY_s +  \int_0^t \frac{\partial F}{dy}(X_s, Y_s)  dX_s \\
&+ \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\frac{\partial^2 F}{dx^2}(X_s, Y_s) d\langle Y, Y\rangle_s +
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \frac{\partial^2 F}{dy^2}(X_s, Y_s) d\langle X, X\rangle_s \\ &+
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \frac{\partial^2 F}{dx \,dy}(X_s, Y_s) d\langle X, Y\rangle_s 
\end{align}

However, it seems that when applied to 1) $X_t = t$ and $Y_t = B_t$ (Brownian motion in 1D) , or 2) $X_t$ local martingale and $Y_t = \langle X, X \rangle_t$, the last two integrals  disappear in the formulas I've seen.

Why is that so ?

Comment: Because the quadratic covariation $\langle f, g \rangle$ equals zero if $f$ is continuous and $g$ of bounded variation

Comment: Because $dtdB_t = o(t^{3/2})$ and $(dB_t)^2 = dt$. In the first case when, you expand the terms $d[X,X]_s$ and $d[X,Y]_s$, you get things which are $o(ds^\alpha)$ with $\alpha>1$ and so can be thrown away.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1351694/168758.

Comment: Thank you, @dohmatob I think that using small o notation here is somewhat of an abuse, and also does not explain the result for the martingale. But it's still useful as mnemonics!

Comment: My comment was for the first of your cases. For the second, you'll need to provide more details / refs. It's usually best to post questions which are self-contained, in terms of terminology, etc.

Comment: BTW, I've upvoted your question. Good stuff :)